# View is not visible in Constraint layout

Tags: android, xml

In the Constraint layout I have a Button and on top of it is an **Image View(id==R.id.imageView)** which is aligned **center-right** area of the Button.The background of the Image View is a white colored right arrow. In design view and in my device the Image View is not displayed. I cleaned and build the project but the problem persists.In the Image below the blue rectangular portion is then area where the Image should be displayed.Please provide a solution for this...

**Design Preview:**

[image]

**XML:**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/head"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/ph_verify_lbl_mrgn"
    android:text="@string/verify_your_phone_number"
    android:textColor="#bb2b67"
    android:textSize="@dimen/ph_verify_head_tsxtsze"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum_lorem_ipsum"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/head" />

 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:hint="@string/ph_hint"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"

    android:background="@drawable/arrow"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.909"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.571" />

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="89dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
    android:text="@string/next"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.25" />

   </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the `ImageView` tag below the `Button` tag.
Since you have provided match parent to the button and set the constraints to fill horizontally, the ImageView is being overlapped.

You can test it by keeping property of `Button` `clickable="false"` and put a click listener on the `ImageView`

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="89dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
    android:text="@string/next"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.25" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"

    android:background="@drawable/arrow"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.909"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.571" />
```

**UPDATE**

Also if this does not work, put an elevation to the `ImageView`

`android:elevation="2dp"`

Comment: set the imageview tag below button and also set clickable to false.Still not displayed

Comment: Try putting a background to the ImageView of a SOLID color and see if you see the result.

Comment: In relativelayout I used to do it as you suggested, but in constraint layout it doesn't help

Comment: Still the same.What to do now

Comment: See the update. I tried it and it worked for me. Cheers :)

Comment: That works .....I thought u said button overlaps.But how did elevation help

Comment: The button did overlap the ImageView otherwise the elevation attribute wouldn't have worked. ImageView is a flat view, whereas a button is Clickable view by default it has an elevation. I "think" this was the issue

Comment: Upvoted and accepted as answer.That gives you a power boost.Thank you.

Comment: @Geet..Just 1 prblm I faced.When the button is clicked the ImageView blinks..Any way to solve that prblm??

Comment: Increate the elevation of the ImageView